# What should I do if anything related to database communication goes wrong?

Tags: php

Here's the problem: When a script starts modifying the database and something goes wrong, the database is usually corrupted. For example, lets say we have a User table and a Photos table.

A script creates a user dataset and in the next lines it attempts to create a photo dataset. The photo has a user_id column. Now lets assume something goes wrong and PDO's lastInserId() doesn't return the id of the user. So what happens in worst case: We get a user with no photo, and a photo with no valid user_id. Broken reference. 3 weeks to debug.

Are there any good strategies to follow, to prevent exactly this kind of problems? In my code below, you can see that I at least try to log that to a file and quit the script execution to prevent more damage and db curruption.

```
public function lastInsertId() {
    $id = $this->dbh->lastInsertId();
    if (!is_numeric($id)) {
        $this->logError("DB::lastInsertId() did not return an id as expected!");
        die();
    }
    return $id;
}
```

Maybe I have to use Transactions all over the place, at any time where an query B depends on a query A, and so forth? Is that the solution to go?

Should I do a "precaution rollback" before the die() call? I guess it would not hurt much at this point, would it? I'm not sure...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution would be to use transactions each time you have several queries for which it should be "all or none", yes -- that's the **A** of [ACID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID#Atomicity) : Atomicity.

You can do a `rollback` before your `die`, if you want ; it won't change much *(a transaction that is not commited will automatically be rolled-back by the DB engine)*, but it will make your code more clear, and easier to understand.

As a sidenote : using `die` this way is probably not the "right" way to deal with errors : it'll prevent you from displaying any kind of "nice" error page, for instance.

A solution that's more often used is to have some kind of exception be thrown when there is such kind of problem -- and in a higher layer of your application *(in one single place)* deal with those exceptions, to display an error page.

Answer (score 1):

Outside of using a transactional engine (InnoDB if you're using [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/), or just use [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org), etc.) and wrapping the relevant atomic activities there's not a great deal you can do.

As @Seb says, you can create a transactional log and you could even use a master/slave database setup, but this won't really add much in terms of coverage.

Answer (score 0):

You should keep a log of all transactions, so if the automated process goes wrong (even your rollbacks, fallback procedures, etc), you still can revert all effects back manually.

Comment: Implementing transaction semantics is the job of the database. That's what it's designed for. Otherwise you could just use ordinary file io.